# How can I do the previous and next on pagination in Vue.js?

Tags: vue.js, pagination

I'm having trouble with the previous and next on pagination. Can somebody help how can I do the previous and next on pagination? I want my pagination looks like this Previous 1 2 3 Next. Here's my jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/cspzm21o/2/

```
  pagination : function(activePage) {
                this.currentPage = activePage;
                this.startIndex = (this.currentPage * 10) - 10;
                this.endIndex = this.startIndex + 10;
            },

  previous : function() {
                this.startIndex--;
            },
  next : function() {
                this.startIndex++;
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're just incrementing/decrementing the startIndex in previous and next method. Instead you could do something like this:

```
previous : function() {
    this.pagination(this.currentPage - 1);
},
next : function() {
    this.pagination(this.currentPage + 1);
}
```